# grep for process id to get the correct value

Tags: linux

I am using the grep command to get a specific process id, but sometimes i am getting two process ids and my output is not correct.

```
 ps -ef |grep AS_Cluster.js
root      2711  2624  0 07:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep AS_Cluster.js
root     14630 14625  0 Sep13 ?        00:32:36 node xx/x/xx/x/xx/AS_Cluster.js
```

I want to get the pid value of only node `xx/xxx/xx/AS_Cluster.js`   this process id. Any help
 on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
ps -ef | grep AS_Cluster.js | grep -v grep
```

Comment: `pgrep` is shorter and the command above gives much more than a pid

Answer (score 1):

Use preferably [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) (probably as `pgrep -f AS_cluster.js`) or pipe the output of `ps` to some `awk` command (see [gawk(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html)) or script.